# Filtering inside the List

Tags: c#

Firstly,i fill in the list with some objects with different propetries and afterwards I'd like to remove all inappropriate objects from this list.
For sure, it throws an exception, saying that the list has been modified and it leads to problems with enumeration. How to manage this and remove all inappropriate objects without using another List, for example, ListFiltred, where I can add all appropriate objects?

```
MyList.Add(new Houses() { Number = "04" });
MyList.Add(new Houses() { Number = "01" });
MyList.Add(new Houses() { Number = "02" });
MyList.Add(new Houses() { Number = "04" });
MyList.Add(new Houses() { Number = "04" });
foreach (var item in MyList)
{
    if (item.Number != "04")
    {
        MyList.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use linq `Where` to do it in one line `var res = MyList.Where(i => i == "04").ToList()`

Comment: You cannot modify a list while iterating through it using `foreach`.  Like @dcg said you should just use LINQ.

Comment: @dcg: That uses another List which the OP said they didn't want. Fortunately there is a method on List that removes everything defined by a predicate you pass which I assume would be better performance than the LINQ way anyway. Moral of the story - check to see if there is already a method to do what you want before falling back to LINQ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`List<T>` has a [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method that takes a predicate. You can use it like this:

```
MyList.RemoveAll(x=>x.Number != "04");
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)** direct method

```
MyList.RemoveAll(val=>val.Number != "04");
```